# In CentOS7 how to allow email address with adduser command?

Tags: centos, useradd

In ubuntu it is possible to use the following:

```
sudo adduser --force-badname john.smith@example.com
```

This allows adding an email address as a username. The --force-badname option doesn't work in CentOS 7.

Is there a way to achieve this in CentOS 7?

Comment: Why the Ubuntu tag?

Comment: Keep in mind that users on this host would not be able to receive email without significant tweaks to most out-of-the-box MTA configurations, as `john.smith@example.com@example.com` is not a valid email address (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible on CentOS 7 using the `useradd` or `adduser` command. This following patch prevents it and there's no `--force-badname` option: https://git.centos.org/blob/rpms!shadow-utils.git/c7/SOURCES!shadow-4.1.5.1-goodname.patch

You can achieve this by adding the user `john.smithATSYMBOLexample.com` and using `vipw` to do `s/ATSYMBOL/@/` . It appears vipw doesn't check validity of usernames.

Comment: I have not used vipw before @mmckinst . Can you tell me exactly how to achieve this with vipw? Please note I am not a sysadmin

Comment: its just a way to edit /etc/passwd, it uses a lockfile to prevent multiple people from editing it at the same time. You could just do sed instead if you want to automate it.

Comment: We got this working with sed:

`sudo adduser john.smithATexample.com`

`sudo sed -i 's/john.smithATexample.com/john.smith@example.com/g' /etc/passwd`

`sudo sed -i 's/john.smithATexample.com/john.smith@example.com/g' /etc/shadow`